Cannot see logs in aws CloudWatch for failed Service deployment (Updated: GPU resource insufficient error)
I set up the container (in the Task definition) to use CloudWatch logs:

When I deploy the Services (via Task > Deploy > Create Service),
it fails with "ECS deployment circuit breaker: tasks failed to start."
(same error as here: Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered'." - as per their comments, I need to view the logs, but I cannot seem to see them anywhere - CloudWatch logs are completely empty)
Like the poster above, I am also running a very small python3 flask wepabb (basically a 'hello world' application), which builds and runs fine on my local machine.
Any help much appreciated
--- EDIT:
Ok so turns out because the container never got launched, no logs created (permissions were assigned to the task)
Under Cluster [my cluster] > Services > [my service] > Events tab:
I now repeatedly get this:

During cluster create, I used a1.medium (arm64 - since I built the image locally on my mac M2 which is arm64)...
I tried using Amazon Linux 2 (arm64) as well ... no luck (same error)
This error is specifically about GPU resources ...
On the EC2 instance for this cluster, I can't seem to see any info about GPU resources for the instance (?)
Why would a simple python flask app require GPU resources?

It sounds like the IAM role you assked to the ECS task as the IAM Execution Role does not have AWS CloudWatch Logs permissions. Or you didn't assign an IAM Execution Role to the task at all.


During cluster create, I used a1.medium (arm64 - since I built the image locally on my mac M2 which is arm64)...
I tried using Amazon Linux 2 (arm64) as well ... no luck (same error)

You are just trying different CPUs here. You haven't done anything to select an instance with a GPU. You are requiring GPU support in your ECS task, so you have to add EC2 instances to your ECS cluster that actually have a GPU. Most EC2 instance types do not have GPUs. See the Accelerated Computing section in the EC2 Instance Types list. You need to pick an instance type from that list. Since you are also building your images for an ARM CPU environment, I suggest trying the G5g instance type.

Thanks @MarkB, I don't have G5g instance type in my dropdown list when creating a new cluster (only g5, and these are huge - overkill for this tiny flask app... I think issue here is I don't need GPU at all)
